# What was the Gothic language name for Ravenna?

Tags: ancient-history, toponymy, goths

I'm trying to surmise what was/might have been the Gothic name for Ravenna, which served as the Ostrogothic capital for some time. Gothic *does* have the sounds to emulate the Latin pronunciation (Rawenna), so would it have stayed the same, or is there a different, historically attested name that the Goths used for the city?

Comment: This seems like a history question more than a linguistics question. Linguists might know details about the Gothic language, but historians are more likely to have sources on a particular city's name in the past, I'd think.

Comment: P.S. there's [history.se]

Answer (score 14):

Gothic is mainly preserved in the form of incomplete Bibles, of which the most well known is the [Codex Argenteus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Argenteus) (now in Uppsala).

Apart from these, there are a few very short texts, most of which are also dealing with religious matters. [The Wulfila project](http://www.wulfila.be/gothic/) collects almost everything there is, and is also hosting a [dictionary](http://www.wulfila.be/lib/streitberg/1910/text/html/) (from 1919, but since then, the only text has been found is one of the missing pages from the Codex Argenteus). The closest word to "Ravenna" in the dictionary is probably "Raibaikka", '[Rebecca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebecca)'

There are a couple more sources for Gothic, but they are equally silent on this matter: a few very short [runic inscriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_runic_inscriptions), and the short dictionary of Crimean Gothic [Ogier Ghiselin de Busbecq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogier_Ghiselin_de_Busbecq) produced in the 16th century. The Wulfila dictionary might have missed a gloss of the city name in some text mainly in another language, but that seems very unlikely.

Answer (score -3):

The Gothic name for Ravenna is  (Rabainna) [raβɛːnːa]/[ravɛːnːa]. Finding this out is as easy as finding the word “Ravenna” in Wikipedia and then switching the article to the Gothic language.
[https://got.wikipedia.org/wiki/](https://got.wikipedia.org/wiki/%F0%90%8D%82%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8C%B1%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8C%B9%F0%90%8C%BD%F0%90%8C%BD%F0%90%8C%B0)

Comment: Do you have any Gothic evidence for the Gothic name of Ravenna? As you know, the internet was not around when Gothic was actually spoken.

Comment: Good find, but I suspect it may just be a modern transliteration from the Latin.

Comment: @Draconis - Naturally it is modern, the Gothic name of Ravenna is not attested in the corpus of the Gothic texts we know, at least none of the dictionaries I have which include place names don't have anything like “Ravenna”. Still I guess the person who dared to write a Wiki article on Ravenna in Gothic had some ground and background to spell it exactly like that.

Comment: @Draconis - I'm not a specialist of Gothic although I did study it and I agree that this form, , is pretty consistent and agrees with how Gothic rendered other place names, see the [place names section](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=TG8HAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) in 1867 _Gotisches Woerterbuch_ by Ernst Schulze, the place names section begins from page 230 in the book. Gothic based its spelling of place names on Greek orthography.

Comment: @YellowSky Considering that the question specifically asks for a _historically attested_ name, I think it would be a better answer to say that and supply the Wikipedia name as an additional note.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - In fact, the question specifically asks for what the name of Ravenna _might have been_ in Gothic, it's explicitly written in the question.

Comment: @YellowSky That part of the question is off topic. Speculations about what something might potentially have hypothetically been are not on topic. The subsequent part, whether there is an actually attested name for the city, is on topic and should take precedence.

Comment: A transliteration made up by somebody in the 21st century, however plausible, is not a useful answer to the question, at least without a big red message saying "Warning: this is made up!"

Comment: It seems to me that this could be made into a useful -- if not complete -- answer if the many excellent points raised (and answered) in the comments were merged in.

Comment: Cities sometimes have very different names in different languages. This looks very suspicious.

Comment: Seems unlikely because I can’t find mentions of that name or its transliteration elsewhere on the internet on pages that also contain *ravenna*.